# cgroup same process with different resources

Tags: centos, jboss, linux-kernel, cgroup

I have a Jboss application server installed through source and running multiple instances(say 3) of JBoss as a same user in a single machine on different ports.
Using cgroups, I'm trying to do distinct resource allocation for each instance that i start. I know cgclassify can attach a process to a cgroup but i dont want this. Ideally I need a way to start the instance/process itself with a corresponding cggroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [cgexec](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/Starting_a_Process.html):

```
cgexec -g subsystems:path_to_cgroup command arguments
```